# Can't resolve this Java generics compile-time warning

Tags: java, generics, observer-pattern

Please consider the following code:

```
public abstract class Subject {
    private Collection<Observer> observerCollection = new HashSet<>();
    // ...
    protected void notifyObservers() {
        this.observerCollection.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(o -> o.update(this));
    }
}

public interface Observer<T extends Subject> {
    void update(T subject);
}
```

I am getting the following compile-time warnings:

> Observer is a raw type. References to generic type Observer should be parameterized
>
> Type safety: The method update(Subject) belongs to the raw type Observer. References to generic type Observer should be parameterized

One comes at the call to `update` and for the life of me I can't figure out how to resolve it without using the warning suppressions. I've tried several ways to resolve the warning without luck. Any ideas on how this can be resolved?

### Motivation

Consider the following client code:

```
public class IntegerContainer extends Subject {
    private int integer;
    
    public IntegerContainer(int integer) {
        this.integer = integer;
    }

    public int getInteger() {
        return this.integer;
    } // ...
}

public class IntegerObserver implements Observer<IntegerContainer> {
    private int cachedInteger;

    @Override
    public void update(IntegerContainer subject) {
        this.cachedInteger = subject.getInteger(); // avoid cast here.
    } // ...
}
```

The motivation for using generics in the `Observer` is to avoid a cast of the `subject` parameter so that the observer can retrieve the state of the subject.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes, I've tried with the same result. I agree but just `Collection<Observer>` gives me a `rawtype` and an `unchecked` warning.

Comment: You're using raw types. Don't do that. Also, don't name your type the same as well-known Java API types, especially not from the `java.lang....` or `java.util....` packages.

Comment: I'd like to take a step back: why do you need the Subject generic type? What kind of constraints do you want to enforce? I believe this `Observer.update` would allow pretty much every Subject and all their respective observers: `void update(Subject subject);` .

Comment: @TamasRev Great question! In the `update()` method of a class implementing `Observer<T extends Subject>`, I wanted to avoid a cast of the`Subject` parameter to a particular type in order to receive the state update. I'll augment the question to include a motivation.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have anything to do with streams; it just straight up won't work.

An `Observer<? extends Subject>` is more or less unusable, because you don't know what subtype of `Subject` it's an observer of.  For all you know, `observerCollection` only contains an `Observer<SomeSubtypeOfSubjectThatNobodyEvenHeardOf>`.  (See the [PECS principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super); `Observer` is a consumer.)

I don't think there's *any* type-safe way to do this cleanly, frankly, because you can't say in `Subject` that the attached observers all accept this subtype of Subject, because there's no way to refer to "this subtype of Subject."  The closest hack I can think of is

```
abstract class Subject<T extends Subject<T>> {
  private Collection<Observer<? super T>> observers;
  protected void notifyObservers() {
    this.observerCollection.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(o -> o.update((T) this)); // yes, this cast is unchecked
  }
}

class SubSubject extends Subject<SubSubject> {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hm. Maybe I should change the question into how to avoid the warning.

Comment: Does the question make more sense now? Does it change your answer?

Comment: Not at all.  There is no approach that will avoid the warning, not really, other than giving up on `Subject` entirely and having each of its subtypes do the observer stuff themselves.

Comment: I don't know what the question looked like before the edit, but at the moment it's still showing the use of `Observer` (bad simple name) as a raw type.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Hm, but `this` is a `Subject` and `update()` takes a parameter of type `T` and `T` is defined to be some type extending `Subject`. I guess it boils down to whether a type "extends" itself, which think it ought to be considered as such.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian, there is no way to convince the compiler that `this` is of type `T` other than an unsafe cast.

Comment: @LouisWasserman That seems strange to me. It can't infer that `this` is in a method declared in the `Subject` class and that the upper bound of `T` is `Subject`?

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian, it can figure out both of those, but those premises aren't enough to prove that `this` is a `T`.  `this` could be some _other_ subtype of `Subject`, besides `T`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd focus on the value being passed between the `Subject` and `Observer`. I.e. both classes have one type parameter and the related methods make sure that the types are compatible:

```
public interface Observer<T> {
    void update(T value); // no subject, but a value
}

public class Subject<T> {
      private Collection<Observer<? super T>> observers = new HashSet<>();

      protected void notifyObservers() {
        this.observers.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(o -> o.update(this.getValue()));
      }

      public void addObserver(Observer<T> observer) { // adding the right kind of observer
          observers.add(observer);
      }

      abstract public T getValue(); // returning the value - this one is abstract
}
```

The key above is the `abstract public T getValue();` method. Here is how you can write an `IntegerContainer` and and `IntegerObserver` :

```
public class IntegerContainer extends Subject<Integer> {

    private int value;

    public IntegerContainer(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getValue() {
        return value; // this is the parameter of the update() call
        // you could even compute here something
        // you can pass entire objects too, if required
    }

}

public class IntegerObserver implements Observer<Integer> {
    private int cachedInteger;

    @Override
    public void update(Integer value) {
        this.cachedInteger = value; // no cast here
    } // ...
}
```

You can put them together like this:

```
IntegerContainer container = new IntegerContainer(3);
IntegerObserver observer = new IntegerObserver();
container.addObserver(observer);
container.notifyObservers();
```